# Configuration File (php.ini) Path C:\WINDOWS

Tags: php, apache

System: Windows 10 x64

apache: httpd-2.4.16-x64-vc11

php:    php-5.6.12-Win32-VC11-x64

In httpd.conf I add this:

```
# 
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

Now I can see the `phpinfo()`'s result. But the `Configuration File (php.ini) Path` is always `C:\WINDOWS`, the `Loaded Configuration File` is always `none`.

I have tryed:

1. Replace the '/' with '\' in `PHPIniDir`
2. Add '/' or '\' in the end of `PHPIniDir` like `C:/php/` or `C:\php\`
3. Use the absolute path of `php.ini`
4. Add php directory in the path
5. Add `PHPRC` in the `Environment Variable`
6. Move the `PHPIniDir` item to the above of `LoadModule php5_module"c:/php/php5apache2.dll"`
7. Search in regedit.exe for `IniFilePath`

Dont't solved my problem, please help!

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem. Before I use ApacheHaus, but php may don't adopted this version of appache, Now I use Apache Lounge so everything is right.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in ApacheHaus with PHP for Windows.

The issue was fixed in ApacheHaus when I found out the php.ini file in `C:\php\` has an extension to its filename.

```sh
C:\php\php.ini-production
```

**Solution:**
Created a new file `php.ini` in `C:\php\` and copy-pasted the content of php.ini-production to the new file and restarted the Apache Server, it worked.

In httpd.conf, Apache Settings

```
# configure the path to php.ini
PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

The fix for ApacheHaus and PHP for Windows was to create a new php.ini

Answer (score 0):

your added this

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2.dll"
```

look to the old directory it may looks like

```
  LoadModule php6_module "c:/AppServ\php\php5apache2_2.dll"
```

please look into directory and make sure what is the name exactly , is it php not php5 etc ... and if php5 change it to this `c:/AppServ\**php5**\php5apache2_2.dll"`

Comment: I have resolved this problem. Before I use ApacheHaus, but php may don't adopted this version of appache, Now I use Apache Lounge so everything is right.

Answer (score 0):

> C:\Users\piesc>php --ini
>   Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
>   Loaded Configuration File:         C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\php.ini
>   Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
>   Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

I had to add a php.ini file to the Configuration File in:

`C:\xampp\php\php.ini`